# Обработчик мыши

Tags: delphi

Нужен обработчик мыши для канвы. Если при нажатии на левую кнопку мыши по форме и при нажатой мышке потянуть влево, то фигура поворачивается влево, соответственно, направо. Если же нажата правая кнопка мыши и она поворачивается влево, то фигура увеличивается, соответственно, вправо.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте воспользоваться следующими функциями, если вы, конечно, рисуете на Канвасе VCL компонентов, например, TImage или TForm (по сути мало разницы):

```
MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
```

В первой ожидаете нажатия кнопки мыши (фиксируя кнопку, координаты и что там вам еще нужно), из `Button: TMouseButton` можете выковырять какая кнопка мыши нажата. Во второй - обрабатываете движение курсора. Разница между начальным (`X, Y: Integer` из `MouseDown`) и текущим (`X, Y: Integer` из `MouseMove`) положением - это ваш масштаб или угол поворота. В третьей - вы "отлавливаете" отпускание кнопки мыши, дабы остановить масштабирование или поворот.

Хотя, имхо, может, стоило бы масштабировать колесиком? В таком случае воспользуйтесь событиями `MouseWheel или MouseWheelDown|MouseWheelUp`.

Для иных случаев, конечно, придется изучить то, что предложил [[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov).

Comment: Компонент TCanvas в Delphi не поддерживает 3D графику! Ни о каких поворотах/движениях фигур и речи быть не может( только если автор вопроса не пишет свой 3D движок для канвы) ). И функции, приведенные вами, позволят нарисовать именно двумерный объект( прямоугольник, эллипсис, линию ) и не больше!

Comment: Сурьезно?

- Квадрат, прямоугольник, эллипс не вращается и не масштабируется?
- Вокруг начала координат тоже нельзя их вращать?
- А вдруг пишет? Несколько функций базовых 3д преобразований, элементарных причем, и работает все на ура. Включая скрытие невидимых граней и показ теней.
- Функции, приведенные мной, вообще ничего рисовать не позволяют.

Comment: Все, дискуссии не будет? Поналяпал минусов и сбежал? И так всегда, как же это печально.

Comment: @Dex, функции, приведенные вами именно позволяют нарисовать мышью то, о чем я писал выше. Я не так выразился. О масштабировании я ничего не говорил, как вы, надеюсь, заметили. А вот вращение уже будет, только, как вы сами сказали по поводу написания движка в третьем пункте: 

      А вдруг пишет? Несколько функций базовых 3д преобразований, элементарных причем, и работает все на ура (а у некоторых даже быстро). Включая скрытие невидимых граней и показ теней.

Comment: Данные функции не имеют непосредственного функционала для прорисовки. Они предоставляют только кнопки, координаты и компонент у которого сработало данное событие.

Answer (score 1):

Канва - это холст, на нем рисуют. Объектов на канве нет, там есть пиксели с разными цветами. Для обработки пользовательских действий работать надо с внутренними структурами, представляющими рисуемые объекты, и выводить их на канву (рисовать и перерисовывать) при необходимости.

Движения и нажатия мыши отслеживайте в соответствующих обработчиках событий WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_MOUSEDOWN, WM_MOUSEUP...